# Was this too heavy of a dup hammer?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question

I'm still learning what a *dup* is. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42423119/prepend-element-to-beginning-of-array-swift) question qualifies? The *specific* answer to this *specific* question is pretty much buried in the **much** accepted answer. As in three examples deep - in a question I certainly wouldn't have thought of doing a query on. ("Add" does not mean "Prepend".)

Because I really only work the Swift tag I have no clue how other tags are with reviewing their queues. Was this really a duplicate of a question that has an answer? An *easily* searched for answer? It was a good question…

Comment: By the looks of it the answers don't bring much new value that isn't already covered by the answers on the dupe.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, that question is definitely a duplicate. Prepending an element is just adding it at the beginning after all. And as you've said yourself, the accepted answer to the "original" question also covers this case. (It is also updated to Swift 3)

Marking a question as a duplicate doesn't necessarily mean that it's a bad question or that the asker didn't try to search for the answer (most of the times this is true however). By marking this question as a duplicate it makes it easier for people to search for this issue in different ways and still get redirected to the same high quality answer that provides all the information they need.

The duplicate question can also be voted on after being closed, so if you feel like it's still a good and helpful question (that just happens to be answered somewhere else) you can/should upvote it.

Comment: I stand corrected. I'm still learning this 'dup' thing an really thought a Q & A site (even if for professionals) would want things more specific than the dup'ed link was. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002733/add-an-element-to-an-array-in-swift) in the duplicate question says:

> To insert a single object at the beginning of the array, you can use
>   the insert method.
>
> `anArray.insert("This String", atIndex: 0)`

which exactly answers the closed question. So closing it as a duplicate looks very reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing here is an example of using a "canonical target" for duplicate closure.

Often, when a question is asked many times, dozens or sometimes hundreds, the community that is familiar with answering that question will decide on a post that answers the question, perhaps sometimes broadly. That is the scenario here.

When these targets are used, they are often taken good care of as well, and tend to include a larger amount of content than an average one liner answer would contain. Given this, it is usually assumed that the canonical post is more helpful to the asker as well.

The downvotes on such questions tend to fall in the category of "lack of research" by the same group that sees that type of question very often, sometimes multiple times per day (I'm looking at you null reference).

Overall, sometimes it may seem like questions get hammered that were stand-alone, but often that is the result of wanting the higher quality, well maintained (canonical) post to reach more users in need.

Comment: I've learned that "thank you" comments don't belong on SO - I also understand. If they can belong on MSO then please, thanks! This is a great explanation of things. I'll need a bit of time to process it properly. ;-)

Comment: @dfd "thank you" comments are a bit more tolerated on Meta, but rarely bring any value (either on main or Meta). So unless you have constructive feedback in addition to "thanks" it is better to just vote.